# What is the definitive way to tell if a class is included in the uap-10.0 profile?

Tags: c#, .net, uwp, .net-core

For example, the [CryptoStream](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.cryptostream(v=vs.110).aspx) documentation clearly states:

**Universal Windows Platfom**
Available Since 10

However, the entire Internet disagrees and says to use `Windows.Security.Cryptography` to do crypto operations.  This namespace does not contain the `CryptoStream` class and has no way to do streaming decrypt operations (that I can find, and no I don't want to simply read the entire stream into memory to decrypt it).  This is by far not the only example of this confusing situation.  What can I use and what can't I?  Users cry out for UWP support from the library I am developing, but I am stumbling around in the dark trying to find out how to properly give it.